# node.js keep the local variable in function, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question when I do the node.js async coding.
Here is the example codes:

```
function foo(arg) {
  var a = arg;
  console.log(a + ' start');
  setTimeout(function () {console.log(a);}, 500);
};
foo(1);
foo(2);
```

It outputs:

```
1 start
2 start
1
2
```

I'm confused. I thought it should output↓, because the local variable is changed by the foo(2)

```
1 start
2 start
2
2
```

Could you guys please tell me why/how node.js keep the local variable for the internal callback function access?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The concept you are looking for is [closures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it is a local variable, not a global. That's the point of local variables.

`var a` creates a variable that exists for the life time of the function call. Declaring a function inside it extends the lifetime to cover that function too. When the anonymous function is called it continues to use the `a` that exists in the scope that it was created in.

Since you call the outer function twice, you have two `a`s. One for each call. You have two anonymous functions, one for each call. Each anonymous function was created in the same scope as one of the `a`s.

Comment: "Declaring a function inside it extends the lifetime to cover that function too."
you explained it very clearly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript variables are scoped by function declarations, not by blocks. Thus, you are using two different variables.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Got it, I'm a new comer to Javascript:)

Answer (score 1):

It's working exactly as it should be.
You declared the variable `a` inside your function with `var a;` and that, how you know, declare a local variable. The callback of `setTimeout` is inside the same scope as your function is (and so is your `var a`).
That being said it's only a matter of understanding how scopes works.
Here is an old and good post about it: http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/

Or you can just search for 'javascript scopes' on google and you will find plenty of a reference.